# Estimating probability density for forecasts

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, forecasting, prediction, prediction-interval

I've used a handful of algorithms for forecasting future values in a
time series. But sometimes what I'm really interested in is not the
predicted value, but the probability that some future will be below (or
above) some threshold.

So **I'm trying to figure out a way to turn the output of a forecast into
an *estimate* of probability.** Forecast algorithms usually return, at
minimum, a prediction and a confidence interval (often 95%). So perhaps
I could make the assumption that the probability density function is
normally distributed, centred on the prediction.

If $x_{pred}$ is the prediction, the probability density would be

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} } e^{ -\frac{(x-x_{pred})^2}{2\sigma^2} }$

So next I need to know (or estimate) $\sigma$.
The 95% confidence interval is

$x_{pred} \pm 1.960 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$,

so I can calculate $\sigma$ if I know (or can estimate) n.
**Would it make any sense to set $n \approx$ the number of data points used
in making the forecast?**

Alternatively, forecast models often provide the standard error. **Would
it make any sense to use this as an estimate of $\sigma$?**

In theory, I could re-implement a standard algorithm to get access to the
information I need. However, I want to be able to use existing
implementations, including ones that might be available in future.

Comment: I would definitely have a look at Gaussian Processes. They do exactly those things that you describe: the predictive distribution is a normal distribution with parameters influenced by the current x input and the training data. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process, https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vU6AiEYED9E and so forth...

Comment: You are using the term *confidence interval* where *prediction interval* is more appropriate.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410806/estimating-when-a-time-series-with-random-spikes-crosses-a-threshold-for-the-fir/412069#412069 will be of help to you.

Comment: @FabianWerner that looks like exactly what I need. If you want to turn that into an answer, I'll accept it.