# Forecasting time point not value

Tags: time-series, forecasting, prediction-interval, forecast-combination, forecastability

I have a simple question.
when we want to forecast a time series, we always focus on the value of series in future. But could we forecast time point of spesific value? For example I would like to forecast when the inflation rate will be 10.5%? 
Thanks...

Comment: if you search for *threshold crossing* in time series you may turn up some relevant links

Comment: Thank you for advice.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410806/estimating-when-a-time-series-with-random-spikes-crosses-a-threshold-for-the-fir/412069#412069 or simply search for threshold . This post did not come up when I searched for "threshold crossing"

Comment: When I searched “threshold” I saw Threshold models in time series. I also study structural breaks and threshold autoregressive models in my PhD. 2 or 3 years ago, I asked this question a professor from UK. He gave me some keywords but I could not rememeber these. However, I remember non of them is about “threshold”. I guess, his advises about modelling time series with functions that includes variable time and some kind of statistical distribution about time? Of course my memories are not clear :( Thank you very much for reply.